# Passportjs multiple authentication strategies external file with expressjs

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

First off if I am asking a obviously stupid question I apologies in advance.

I have a passport authentication strategy setup currently and it is working ok. The implementation is as follows.

Authentication strategy (authentication.js) :

```
const passport = require("passport");
const passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
const params = {
    //Params here
};


module.exports = function LocalStrategy() {
let strategy = new Strategy(params, function (payload, done) {
    //Logic here
});
passport.use(strategy);
return {
    initialize: function () {
        return passport.initialize();
    },
    authenticate: function () {
        return passport.authenticate("jwt", {
            session: false
        });
    }
  };
};
```

Using in a route :

```
const localAuth = require('./authentication/LocalStrategy')();

app.get('/test', localAuth.authenticate(), (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.isAuthenticated());
});
```

In the server.js file

```
const localAuth = require('./authentication/LocalStrategy')();
app.use(localAuth.initialize());
```

I am planning to use multiple authentication strategies in a single route and I found this [implementation](https://github.com/passport/express-3.x-http-basic-and-digest-example/blob/master/server.js). But rather than having the authentication strategy written in the same server.js I want to have the strategy written in an external file (in my case authentication.js) and refer the strategy in the route as

```
passport.authenticate(['SOME_OTHER_STRATEGY', 'jwt']
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok apparently I was't trying hard enough,
I didn't have to do any change to my current logic other than serializeUser and deserializeUser. and just use:

```
passport.authenticate(['SOME_OTHER_STRATEGY', 'jwt'])
```

that't it.